# I am getting this error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777821/maven-dependency-conflict-org-w3c-dom-elementtraversal) Stack Overflow question before posting here, I tried all solutions in that thread but still it is not working for me. I am migrating a legacy Java project into Spring Boot application.

When I start the server I am getting this stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [static/admin-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:417) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:338) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:224) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources$0(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:390) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:354) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:156) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at com.datalink.DatalinkservicesOldApplication.main(DatalinkservicesOldApplication.java:37) [classes/:na] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getNodeObject(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.12.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.synchronizeChildren(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.12.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.getDocumentElement(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.12.1.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:96) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:511) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
... 24 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
... 66 common frames omitted
```

My [pom.xml](https://github.com/arunan123/stackoverflow/blob/main/pom.xml) is,

This is my dependency graph,

```
 --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:tree (default-cli) @ datalinkservices-old ---
 com.datalink:datalinkservices-old:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.4.4:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.4.4:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.4.4:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.4.4:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.4.4:compile
 |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.13.3:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.13.3:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
 |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
 |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.27:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.4.4:compile
 |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.11.4:compile
 |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.11.4:compile
 |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.11.4:compile
 |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.11.4:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.4.4:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.44:compile
 |  |  +- org.glassfish:jakarta.el:jar:3.0.3:compile
 |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.44:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.5:compile
 |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.5:compile
 +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:jar:3.0.2:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:3.0.2:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:3.0.2:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.4.5:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:3.0.2:compile
 |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.9.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client:jar:3.0.2:compile
 |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-client:jar:1.10.11:compile
 |  |  +- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-eventbus:jar:0.3.0:compile
 |  |  |  +- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-infix:jar:0.3.0:runtime
 |  |  |  |  +- commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3:runtime
 |  |  |  |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:runtime
 |  |  |  |  +- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.4:runtime
 |  |  |  |  |  +- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:runtime
 |  |  |  |  |  \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:runtime
 |  |  |  |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.6:runtime
 |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.2:runtime
 |  |  +- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
 |  |  +- com.netflix.servo:servo-core:jar:0.12.21:compile
 |  |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile
 |  |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.10:compile
 |  |  |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
 |  |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:4.1.0:compile
 |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.11.4:compile
 |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.11.4:compile
 |  |  \- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.4.0:runtime
 |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-core:jar:1.10.11:compile
 |  |  \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:5.3.0:compile
 |  |     \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2:compile
 |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer:jar:3.0.2:compile
 |     +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-loadbalancer:jar:3.0.2:compile
 |     |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.4.4:compile
 |     |  |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.1.7.Final:compile
 |     |  |     +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
 |     |  |     +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
 |     |  |     \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
 |     |  \- io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-extra:jar:3.4.2:compile
 |     +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:jar:2.4.4:compile
 |     |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.3.5:compile
 |     \- com.stoyanr:evictor:jar:1.0.0:compile
 +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.4:compile
 +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.8.0:compile
 +- org.apache.commons:commons-jexl:jar:2.1.1:compile
 +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
 +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.8.0:compile
 +- org.apache.httpcomponents:fluent-hc:jar:4.5.13:compile
 |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.13:compile
 |     \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.14:compile
 +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.13:compile
 +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.12.1:compile
 +- org.apache.flex.blazeds:flex-messaging-common:jar:4.7.3:compile
 +- org.apache.flex.blazeds:flex-messaging-core:jar:4.7.3:compile
 +- org.apache.flex.blazeds:flex-messaging-opt-tomcat-base:jar:4.7.3:compile
 |  \- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.0.1:compile
 |     \- junit:junit:jar:4.13.2:compile
 |        \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.2:compile
 +- org.apache.flex.blazeds:flex-messaging-proxy:jar:4.7.3:compile
 +- org.apache.flex.blazeds:flex-messaging-remoting:jar:4.7.3:compile
 +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2:compile
 |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.2:compile
 +- org.codehaus.castor:castor-core:jar:1.4.1:compile
 |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.11:compile
 +- org.codehaus.castor:castor-xml:jar:1.4.1:compile
 |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1:compile
 |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
 |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.5:compile
 +- org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:jar:2.8.0:compile
 +- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.9.0:compile
 +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:10.0.5:compile
 +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:10.0.5:compile
 +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-servlet-api:jar:10.0.5:compile
 +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
 +- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.2.0:compile
 +- com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:jar:9.3.0.jre8-preview:compile
 +- com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc10:jar:19.10.0.0:compile
 +- net.sf.expectit:expectit-core:jar:0.9.0:compile
 +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:pom:3.0.7:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.5.14:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-ant:jar:2.5.14:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.ant:ant-junit:jar:1.9.15:runtime
 |  |  +- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.9.15:compile
 |  |  \- org.apache.ant:ant-antlr:jar:1.9.15:runtime
 |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-astbuilder:jar:3.0.7:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-cli-picocli:jar:2.5.14:compile
 |  |  \- info.picocli:picocli:jar:4.3.2:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-console:jar:2.5.14:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-datetime:jar:2.5.14:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-docgenerator:jar:2.5.14:compile
 |  |  \- com.thoughtworks.qdox:qdox:jar:1.12.1:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-groovydoc:jar:2.5.14:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-groovysh:jar:2.5.14:compile
 |  |  \- jline:jline:jar:2.14.6:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-jmx:jar:2.5.14:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:jar:2.5.14:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-jsr223:jar:2.5.14:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-macro:jar:2.5.14:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-nio:jar:2.5.14:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-servlet:jar:2.5.14:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-sql:jar:2.5.14:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-swing:jar:2.5.14:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:jar:2.5.14:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-test:jar:2.5.14:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-test-junit5:jar:2.5.14:compile
 |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.7.1:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:compile
 |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:jar:1.7.1:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.7.1:compile
 |  |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.7.1:compile
 |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.7.1:runtime
 |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-testng:jar:2.5.14:compile
 |  |  \- org.testng:testng:jar:6.13.1:runtime
 |  |     \- com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.72:runtime
 |  \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:jar:2.5.14:compile
 +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
 +- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.6.2:compile
 |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
 +- org.json:json:jar:20210307:compile
 +- org.mybatis:mybatis:jar:3.0.6:compile
 +- org.mybatis.caches:mybatis-ehcache:jar:1.0.0-RC1:compile
 |  \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.0.0:compile
 +- org.mybatis:mybatis-spring:jar:1.0.2:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.5:compile
 |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.5:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.5:compile
 |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.3.5:compile
 +- org.netezza:nzjdbc:jar:1.0:system
 +- org.netezza:javax.time:jar:0.6.3:system
 +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:5.0.0:compile
 |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
 |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
 |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
 |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.6.1:compile
 |  \- com.zaxxer:SparseBitSet:jar:1.2:compile
 +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:5.0.0:compile
 |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-lite:jar:5.0.0:compile
 |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.20:compile
 |  +- com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:jar:1.06:compile
 |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.68:compile
 |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.68:compile
 |  +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:2.2.1:compile
 |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-all:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-anim:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-shared-resources:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:jar:1.3.04:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-awt-util:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:xmlgraphics-commons:jar:2.4:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-codec:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-constants:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-dom:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-extension:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-gui-util:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-gvt:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-i18n:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-parser:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-rasterizer-ext:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-rasterizer:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-script:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-slideshow:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-squiggle-ext:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-squiggle:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svg-dom:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svgbrowser:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svggen:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svgpp:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svgrasterizer:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-swing:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ttf2svg:jar:1.13:compile
 |  |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-xml:jar:1.13:compile
 |  \- de.rototor.pdfbox:graphics2d:jar:0.30:compile
 |     \- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:jar:2.0.22:compile
 |        \- org.apache.pdfbox:fontbox:jar:2.0.22:compile
 +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:4.1.2:compile
 |  \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:3.1.0:compile
 +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
 +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
 +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.3.2:compile
 |  \- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.15:compile
 +- org.scriptella:scriptella-core:jar:1.2:compile
 +- org.scriptella:scriptella-drivers:jar:1.2:compile
 +- org.scriptella:scriptella-tools:jar:1.2:compile
 |  \- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.7.1:compile
 +- net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:jar:3.13.2:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.3.5:compile
 |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.6:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-context-indexer:jar:5.3.5:optional
 +- org.springframework:spring-instrument:jar:5.3.5:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:5.3.5:compile
 |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.5:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.3.5:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.3.5:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:5.3.5:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-r2dbc:jar:5.3.5:compile
 |  +- io.r2dbc:r2dbc-spi:jar:0.8.4.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile
 |  \- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.4.4:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-webflux:jar:5.3.5:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-websocket:jar:5.3.5:compile
 +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.4.5:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.5:compile
 |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.5:compile
 +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.4.5:compile
 +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.4.5:compile
 +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:jar:5.4.5:compile
 +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:5.4.5:compile
 +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:5.4.5:compile
 +- org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:jar:2.3.3.RELEASE:compile
 +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:3.3.0:compile
 +- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:9.1:compile
 |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:9.1:compile
 |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:9.1:compile
 +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.1:compile
 +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
 +- com.io7m.xom:xom:jar:1.2.10:compile
 +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.16:compile
 |  \- io.github.x-stream:mxparser:jar:1.2.1:compile
 |     \- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
 +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
 +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.38:compile
 +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.55:compile
 \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.4.4:test
    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.4.4:test
    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.4.4:test
    +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
    |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
    |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
    +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:test
    |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:test
    +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.18.1:test
    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:compile
    +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.7.1:test
    |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.7.1:test
    |     \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.6.28:test
    |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.22:test
    |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.22:test
    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.1:test
    +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.6.28:test
    +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
    |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
    +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.5:test
    \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.7.0:test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I excluded xml-apis and xerces from all the dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
                <groupId>xercesImpl</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.io7m.xom</groupId>
        <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.10</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
                <groupId>xercesImpl</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

and finally added the following dependency,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.01</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

This might have to do with you not using `Generics` with your java `Collections`